# How to change youtube player vars on each video

Tags: javascript, youtube

I can load and play Youtube Video via the iFrame API, but I can't figure out how to change the player parameter for the second video.  I want no controls on the first video and then when user click on my custom Play Video, I want to play the second video  with controls bar.  I can set the playerVars on player initiation, but I don't know how to change it when the player is already loaded.  Any ideas?

Thanks much.

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onPlaybackQualityChange': onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'onError': onPlayerError
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady {
    var $btn = '<button id="play">Play Button</button>';
    $('#nav').prepend($btn);
    $('#play').click(function() {
        player.loadVideoByUrl('http://youtu.be/GBHxL-LXJbs?controls=1');
    });
}
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: And which two videos are you talking about? Where are these functions called? It seems like you simply have to make `playerVars` an parameter of the function.

Comment: it doesn't matter. whether it is a playlist or you set them via `loadVideoById` what he meant is how to change playerVars once they've been set. anyways, you can do this `layer.loadVideoById({'videoId': 'XXX', 'startSeconds': N});`. if it's a playlist you'll probably have to track end/play states  and seek the video depending on what's playing